# Background in app when there is none selected?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new to Swift and app development, so please bear with me. I am slowly developing the UI of my app and, for some reason, when I go to run the app, it shows that there is a background image on the first controller that is different than the one that I specified.

I'm not sure how to explain it other than that. Sorry if it sounds confusing... I'm confused myself.

[image: My story board]

I haven't written any code yet. I created the app and then went straight to the storyboard and started making that the way that I wanted it before I go into the code and change it.

My code, though, is as follows:

**AppDelegate**

```
import UIKit
```

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

}

**RootViewController**

```
import UIKit
```

class RootViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

```
var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Configure the page view controller and add it as a child view controller.
    self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .pageCurl, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    self.pageViewController!.delegate = self

    let startingViewController: DataViewController = self.modelController.viewControllerAtIndex(0, storyboard: self.storyboard!)!
    let viewControllers = [startingViewController]
    self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: {done in })

    self.pageViewController!.dataSource = self.modelController

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController!.view)

    // Set the page view controller's bounds using an inset rect so that self's view is visible around the edges of the pages.
    var pageViewRect = self.view.bounds
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        pageViewRect = pageViewRect.insetBy(dx: 40.0, dy: 40.0)
    }
    self.pageViewController!.view.frame = pageViewRect

    self.pageViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

var modelController: ModelController {
    // Return the model controller object, creating it if necessary.
    // In more complex implementations, the model controller may be passed to the view controller.
    if _modelController == nil {
        _modelController = ModelController()
    }
    return _modelController!
}

var _modelController: ModelController? = nil

// MARK: - UIPageViewController delegate methods

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, spineLocationFor orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation {
    if (orientation == .portrait) || (orientation == .portraitUpsideDown) || (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone) {
        // In portrait orientation or on iPhone: Set the spine position to "min" and the page view controller's view controllers array to contain just one view controller. Setting the spine position to 'UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid' in landscape orientation sets the doubleSided property to true, so set it to false here.
        let currentViewController = self.pageViewController!.viewControllers![0]
        let viewControllers = [currentViewController]
        self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: {done in })

        self.pageViewController!.isDoubleSided = false
        return .min
    }

    // In landscape orientation: Set set the spine location to "mid" and the page view controller's view controllers array to contain two view controllers. If the current page is even, set it to contain the current and next view controllers; if it is odd, set the array to contain the previous and current view controllers.
    let currentViewController = self.pageViewController!.viewControllers![0] as! DataViewController
    var viewControllers: [UIViewController]

    let indexOfCurrentViewController = self.modelController.indexOfViewController(currentViewController)
    if (indexOfCurrentViewController == 0) || (indexOfCurrentViewController % 2 == 0) {
        let nextViewController = self.modelController.pageViewController(self.pageViewController!, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController)
        viewControllers = [currentViewController, nextViewController!]
    } else {
        let previousViewController = self.modelController.pageViewController(self.pageViewController!, viewControllerBefore: currentViewController)
        viewControllers = [previousViewController!, currentViewController]
    }
    self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: {done in })

    return .mid
}
```

}

**DataViewController**
import UIKit

class DataViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var dataLabel: UILabel!
var dataObject: String = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

}

**ModelController**

```
import UIKit
```

/*
 A controller object that manages a simple model -- a collection of month names.

The controller serves as the data source for the page view controller; it therefore implements pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController: and pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:.
 It also implements a custom method, viewControllerAtIndex: which is useful in the implementation of the data source methods, and in the initial configuration of the application.

There is no need to actually create view controllers for each page in advance -- indeed doing so incurs unnecessary overhead. Given the data model, these methods create, configure, and return a new view controller on demand.
 */

class ModelController: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

```
var pageData: [String] = []


override init() {
    super.init()
    // Create the data model.
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    pageData = dateFormatter.monthSymbols
}

func viewControllerAtIndex(_ index: Int, storyboard: UIStoryboard) -> DataViewController? {
    // Return the data view controller for the given index.
    if (self.pageData.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageData.count) {
        return nil
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    let dataViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DataViewController") as! DataViewController
    dataViewController.dataObject = self.pageData[index]
    return dataViewController
}

func indexOfViewController(_ viewController: DataViewController) -> Int {
    // Return the index of the given data view controller.
    // For simplicity, this implementation uses a static array of model objects and the view controller stores the model object; you can therefore use the model object to identify the index.
    return pageData.index(of: viewController.dataObject) ?? NSNotFound
}

// MARK: - Page View Controller Data Source

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = self.indexOfViewController(viewController as! DataViewController)
    if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil
    }

    index -= 1
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index, storyboard: viewController.storyboard!)
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = self.indexOfViewController(viewController as! DataViewController)
    if index == NSNotFound {
        return nil
    }

    index += 1
    if index == self.pageData.count {
        return nil
    }
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index, storyboard: viewController.storyboard!)
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your code, and your storyboard.

Comment: I updated the post with the codes. I'm not sure why the code boxes are behaving like that, though. Could that be because the comments are still there? I haven't touched the code yet--that code was preloaded when I started the project.

Comment: What is " it shows that there is a background image on the first controller that is different than the one that I specifie". Can you explain more?. Or screenshot

Comment: When I run the app in the Simulator, it shows a brown screen when there is no such screen in my Storyboard. I had removed the original controller that came with the project and specified a new one. Yet, the background of the controller on the far left is not the color that you see in the Storyboard above. I don't know how to screenshot that scenario, though.

Comment: I still don't understand it yet. Can you post your demo project?

Comment: How would I do that? I'm new to this website. Sorry! It's not a demo project; it's an actual app that I'm creating.

Comment: Upload your project to GitHub. Then pass link here

Comment: I edited my post here and posted the code. Do you not see it?

Comment: Yes, but I can't investigate the problem. You can post a demo project, remove your business code. Then I can try with it.

Comment: I added no code to the project, though. The only thing that I did was change the Storyboard around, which is why I'm confused. I'm unable to upload to Github. It's confusing...

Comment: They are so many things can cause the problem. I can't help you like this. Try to learn more about iOS.

Comment: I'm just confused how uploading to Github would help. It pretty much is uploading the project and showing the code like I did above, isn't it?

Comment: It's too many things, storyboard properties, plist file, ... Anything can cause the problem. I can't tell you check A, check B, C... . I just have a little time. With my ability, I can't help you. I'm sorry.

Comment: It's okay. Thank you for your time. I'm just confused. I thought that you meant post the code here, so I did. I'm unable to post to Github at the moment.

Comment: Yes. Post code here is the right thing. But I still don't see the problem. Try to check your plist, "main interface", "is initial view controller" property.

Comment: I changed the initial view controller when I deleted the one that was used when my project was opened, so the controller on the far left is the initial one... at least, that's what should be happening when I clicked "Initial View Controller" on that controller.

Comment: Try to delete app, clean the project, then run again

Comment: The app isn't in the App Store. I'm still just building the UI. Should I attempt to Debug it within XCode?

Comment: Delete app in the Simulator, clean project (Xcode menu, product-> clean) then run it again

Comment: But how do you delete it in the Simulator? You said I should try that first, correct?

Comment: yes. Just press and hold your mouse, as you do with app in iPhone.